# Error appeared after changing the deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.4

I am working on IOS project that I tried to test on my iPhone 5, but i got an error that it only runs on IOS 11 (which is not supported for iPhone 5).

So I tried to change the deployment target to 10.3 and test it but I ended up with the following error (Apple Mach-O Linker Error):

[image: Apple Mach-O Linker Error]

The error didn't go even after changing the deployment target back to 11.4

I came across several solutions like [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-xcode-8-apple-mach-o-linker-ld-error-group-in-xcode/89903/6), and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/258) but they didn't solve it for me.

I am afraid that I will have to redo the whole project as it is very time consuming.

Any help will be MASSIVELY appreciated!

Comment: The first thing to try is cleaning your project and rebuilding it

Comment: @Paulw11 i tried and it didn't work

Comment: All of these errors appear to be related to whatever analytics package you are using. Perhaps try removing and re-adding that. Are you using CocoaPods?  If so did you open the project instead of the workspace by mistake?

Comment: @Paulw11 no, i am working in the workspace, i tried removing all cocoapods packages and re-adding them, and still the error persists

Comment: Clear the derived data folder and restart your Mac

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, will do now

Comment: This is a prime reason why using an SCM system like Git is vital, even for solo development.  If your project or workspace or scheme files have been changed by Xcode in any way, not only could you review those changes but you can roll them back to a previous good state if you're using Git.  (And if you're new to Git, or not, check out SmartGit as a GUI client. I have no relationship to them except as a very happy user for last 6 years.)

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, i cleaned the project and it showed me one problem with a package, removed it and installed it again and now the project is working fine. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: @Smartcat I have to agree with you, I am familiar with sourcetree and will use it with this project. thank you for your feedback and help.